# Does Hulk have magically expanding shorts?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

When Banner transforms into Hulk there's usually some shirt-shedding involved, as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPW7uzGbFZ4) demonstrates. Watches, shoes, belts etc. are similarly ripped off. Yet Hulk always seems to be able to keep his shorts, no matter how much he expands.

Obviously, I can appreciate the pragmatic, out-of-universe reason why the comic creators and the film-makers wouldn't want a starkers Hulk running about. **Is there any in-universe explanation for why Hulk rips everything apart from his shorts?**

Answers from either the films or the comics are fine (though I confess I'm not at all familiar with the latter).

Comment: Short answer: They didn't want him nude (out-of-universe.)  In universe, I don't think it's addressed, but Stan Lee suggested that possibly Bruce was friends with Reed Richards and got some, basically, elastic pants (ok; unstable molecules, if you want to be picky -- a staple of the Marvel universe.)  See [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/how-do-the-incredible-hulks-pants-stay-on-but-not-his-shirt), which probably renders this one a duplicate.