# Why is Hulk enormous in "Old Man Logan"?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, old-man-logan

Apart from being villanous, Hulk has two (though likely related) main differences from usual version of Hulk:

- He shows monstrous strength even in his human form
- and he is also freakishly big in his Hulk form, like 3 or 4 times regular Hulk

Is this ever explained?

Comment: Wikipedia implies it's radiation, but doesn't offer any support to that implication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hulk has been interpreted by Mark Millar**

Hulk has been drawn in different ways depending on the artist. The common theme is Banner's inner darkness and unholy rage. Here, the theme Millar seems to be going for is cannibalism. Hulk has been potrayed as the proverbial giant in the clouds, eating his enemies after slaughter. The hulk persona seems to be taking over. Years of depression, angst, PTSD and misery have caused Banner and Hulk to start becoming one. The constant alterations in brain chemistry due to repeatedly hulking out during the uprising as well as after it have caused significant alteration in what we perceive the Hulk and Banner to be.

Aside from thematic understanding, there is little explanation for why Hulk became so monstrous. The extra radiation could have caused Banner to become much larger and retain strength in human in exchange for his weakened healing factor and a destroyed psyche( he was unable to regenerate after Logan grievously injured him).

In a later [interview](https://www.marvel.com/articles/comics/old-man-logan-meeting-the-maestro) Ed Brisson offered his own interpretation of the Hulk

> Maestro is also larger and smarter than the Banner that Logan is used to dealing with. He’s not some hillbilly hiding out in a cave pumping out Hulk babies. He’s got laser focus and the drive to bring about what he wants. And, he’s not going to be stupid about it. He’s not just a couple of fists, smashing everything in sight. He’s got a plan and knows that the best way of carrying out that plan is by keeping a low profile. Or trying to, anyway.

Bruce Banner has been reduced to the status of a hillbilly indicating that the Hulk personality has almost taken over and the true monstrosity of the Hulk is no longer being effectively restrained by Banner.

Answer (score 6):

The Hulk has always varied in size and shape to some extent, due to the continuing effects of Gamma ray mutation on his body. In the main Earth-616 continuity he has changed in size anywhere from 6'6" as the Gray Hulk to 8'8" as the Green Scar. While the form he takes in the events of Old Man Logan is extreme (possibly from additional exposure to radiation from an atomic bomb that exploded over California before the events of the comic) it is consistent with the Hulk's changing appearance over the years.

Comment: There’s a line in the comic from Banner, I think, about the radiation maybe driving him mad.

Comment: I'd love to know where he shops for those pants!

Comment: @Peter-M [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/how-do-the-incredible-hulks-pants-stay-on-but-not-his-shirt/205957?r=SearchResults#205957).