# What are the size limitations of Odo's ability to shape shift?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Odo seems to be able to become quite small (as small as a mouse) and much larger than humanoid form. Is there a limitation to how large (or small) he can become?

Can he become as large as a spaceship? A Planet? Can he change into something as small as a virus?

Comment: Sci-Fi writers generally seem to [ignore problems with mass](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/).

Comment: I'd have to believe his mass is constant, but he has been a rat. Pretty heavy rat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, he was limited to an object of his own mass, or less, as a Changeling, via his Morphogenic Matrix:

From [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Morphogenic_matrix),

> A morphogenic matrix is the cellular and quantum structure of a changeling, which allows them to assume various shapes or forms. It also allows Changelings to shunt some of their mass into another dimension, thereby allowing them to morph into objects with a much smaller mass than themselves.

Note; the limit is equivalent MASS, not size, so a change to something like [fog](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Fog) will permit a much larger area to be covered; in theory, he could become a really large balloon, for example.

As far as I can see, no specific limit on the amount he could shrink himself has been shown.

You may also find these worth looking at:
[Odo's Page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Odo)
[The Changeling Page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Changeling)

Comment: I forget the episode, but it was mentioned once that the more experienced a changling was with shape shifting the larger their "at rest" mass would become, or something to that effect. So over time they could become larger, massier, objects in theory.

Comment: @Xantec: That begs another interesting question--how do changlings grow, since they don't eat or drink? Where would that additional mass come from unless they have some hidden metabolic process that passively absorbs energy from their environment or something?