# comic that explains the genesis of the classic Hulk

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, the-incredible-hulk

Is there a comic book that explains the Genesis of the Hulk? More in tune like from the original live 1978 series? Not the new stuff Grey Hulk etc.. But something classic like the live  hulk series? Or some story close in line with that?

Comment: You realize that the 1978 series wasn't the original incarnation of the Hulk, right?  And the "grey hulk" was part of the history all along?  Because it's making your question unclear.  What exactly are you asking?  Are you looking for the genesis of the actual Hulk, or some kind of comic book origin to the TV version of the Hulk in which they changed a number of things (including the main character's first name!)?

Answer (score 5):

The first Incredible Hulk (The Incredible Hulk #1, 1962) comic, which presents his origins.

http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_1

Comment: Didn't know Hulk was originally grey

Comment: @JeremyFrench: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18196/23243 explains a bit of why the color changed.