# How do the Hulk's cells function biologically?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does The Incredible Hulk change mass?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/how-does-the-incredible-hulk-change-mass)

As we see in the Incredible Hulk movie, the cells of Bruce Banner grow when he becomes "enraged."  Does that mean if the Hulk got too angry and grew really big, would people be able to see an individual cell on the Hulk's body?

If the cells multiply, what happens to the multiplied cells after Bruce reverts back to human form?

Comment: Marvel normally uses something about 'drawn from an extra-dimensional space' to explain mass gain, but I don't see it on the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Robert_Bruce_Banner_%28Earth-616%29); the closest I'm finding it "When the Hulk transforms back into Banner, the excess muscle mass and energy is lost, presumably to the same place he derives it."