# Could The Hulk get stronger if Bruce Banner worked on his own strength?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

In the Marvel movies Bruce Banner is shown to be of average build and when he becomes The Hulk his muscles get way bigger than his own.

I am wondering, if Bruce worked out to build his muscles, when he becomes The Hulk would The Hulk's muscles be even bigger thus becoming even stronger?

Comment: I think the point is moot. The Hulk's [mass comes from elsewhere](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5814/21267), so it wouldn't matter how small/large Bruce Banner is. In fact, they are probably making a point by having a small pip-squeek guy turn into such a tank!

Comment: They actually dealt with this exact thing. Not with the Hulk, but with She-Hulk. I'll see if I can find the relevant issues but basically yes, the strength of the base body is exponentially increased once the person "hulks out".

Answer (score 4):

#### Whether the Hulk could be stronger if Banner had a gym membership may be moot considering the near-limitless nature of the Hulk's strength is purely derived from extra-dimensional mass, the nature of his mental state and apparently independent of Banner's physical condition.

**However:
We do have the opportunity to consider the Hulk from a unique perspective: through the lens of the Red Hulk!**

- **[Thaddeus "Thunderbolt" Ross](http://marvel.wikia.com/Red_Hulk_(Thaddeus_Ross))** was revealed to be the Red Hulk. Ross is a trained soldier, excellent hand-to-hand combatant and was in peak physical condition for a man of his age. Which we can all agree was certainly better shape than the generally out-of-condition, untrained combatant/scientist Bruce Banner has been portrayed as.

[image]

- We have seen the Red Hulk hold his own against foes, some outside of his considerable weight class such as Thor and the Watcher, and he has even fought and defeated Banner's Hulk in combat. We have to assume there may be some relationship to the strength, ruthlessness and physical capacity Ross brings to the Hulk which are more raw in Banner.

[image]

- Does Ross' condition mean he is stronger as the Red Hulk? We can't be sure and I can bet Marvel will never tell us, but we have seen the fact that Ross has had military training, tactics, and fighting skill gives him an advantage over the Hulk, provided the Hulk isn't raging out of control, or becoming planet-wrecking Hulk.

Answer (score 0):

### No, he won't get stronger as Hulk.

#### Why?

Well, Hulk's cousin, Jennifer Walters, had to take some of Hulk's blood which made her the She-Hulk we know today, and when she trained, she did get stronger as She-Hulk. But it won't work on Hulk.

It's simply because She-Hulks strength doesn't increase with rage - it stays the same, always increasing by probably about x1000 when she's She-Hulk compared to human form. But with Hulk, his strength increases with rage, and Bruce's workout will not increase this strength, as the Hulk was made the Hulk not by drinking blood from someone who's Hulk, but by radiation.

Comment: Is there any evidence to support this?